# Get information about the USB device from Win32_DiskDrive and Win32_LogicalDisk

Tags: c#, wmi-query

I want to know the information about a USB device from **Win32_DiskDrive** and **Win32_LogicalDisk.**

I use the following code:

```
private void Add(string letter) // letter is a logical name of the USB device, e.g. "G:\\"
{
  foreach (var drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT DeviceID, SerialNumber, Partitions FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'").Get())
  {
    var partition = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format("ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='{0}'}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition", drive["DeviceID"])).First();

    if (partition != null)
    {
      var logical = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format("ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='{0}'}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition", partition["DeviceID"])).First();

      if (logical != null)
      {
        var volume = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format("SELECT Name, FreeSpace FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE Name='{0}'", logical["Name"])).First();

        string name = (string)volume["Name"];
        string serialNumber = (string)drive["SerialNumber"];
        ulong freeSpace = (ulong)volume["FreeSpace"];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

  public static class WmiExtensions
  {
    // Fetch the first item from the search result collection.
        public static ManagementObject First(this ManagementObjectSearcher searcher)
        {
          ManagementObject result = null;
          foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
          {
            result = item;
            break;
          }
          return result;
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to make it shorter and more elegant?

Comment: @JerryCoffin sorry, it's C#.

Comment: Oh, no need to apologize (but thanks for fixing it).

Comment: Why is your method called `Add`? It doesn't do anything useful. Have you posted edited code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: `Add()` doesn't appear to access any class members, so it can be declared `static`. But then again, it looks like it wants to return the name, serial number, and free space. Make it do so - create a quick container type

```
public sealed class DriveInfo
{
    public DriveInfo(string name, string serialNumber, ulong freeSpace)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.SerialNumber = serialNumber;
        this.FreeSpace = freeSpace;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public string SerialNumber { get; }

    public ulong FreeSpace { get; }
}
```

usage becomes:

```
return new DriveInfo(
    (string)volume["Name"],
    (string)drive["SerialNumber"],
    (ulong)volume["FreeSpace"]);
```

2: The parameter `letter` is completely unused in the method and the comment is a lie. Remove the parameter and comment or use the parameter appropriately.

3: Invert your `if` blocks, to prevent so much indention as well as keeping the tests looking cleaner (equality vs. non-equality):

```
if (partition == null) continue;
...
if (logical == null) continue;
```

4: Both `ManagementObject` and `ManagementObjectSearcher` descend from `Component`, which implements `IDisposable`. Their lifetime should therefore be wrapped in a `using` statement:

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='{drive["DeviceID"]}'}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"))
using (var partition = searcher.First())
{
}
```

5: Your extension method's body can be replaced by a quick one-liner:

`return searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();`